# Как обновить данные в EmbeddedDocument mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

Здравствуйте.
Есть три таблицы

```
class UserCalendarLayer(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):

    i_id = mongoengine.ObjectIdField(default=ObjectId)
    id = mongoengine.StringField()
    summary = mongoengine.StringField()
    time_zone = mongoengine.StringField()
    background_color = mongoengine.StringField()
    foreground_color = mongoengine.StringField()
    access_role = mongoengine.StringField()
    primary = mongoengine.StringField(default="False")
    is_active = mongoengine.StringField(default='True')

class UserCalendar(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):

    i_id = mongoengine.ObjectIdField(default=ObjectId)
    provider = mongoengine.StringField()
    name = mongoengine.StringField(default='primary') #"primary"
    access_data = mongoengine.DictField()
    is_active = mongoengine.StringField(default='True')
    email = mongoengine.StringField()
    calendars_layer = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(UserCalendarLayer))#, default=UserCalendarLayer))

class User(mongoengine.Document, UserMixin):
    user_id = mongoengine.StringField()
    first_name = mongoengine.StringField()
    last_name = mongoengine.StringField()
    contacts = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(UserContact))
    calendars = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(UserCalendar))
```

Мне нужно сделать запрос на обновление данных в модели UserCalendarLayer, у меня есть i_id нужной записи.
Как сделать запрос при помощи mongo или mongoenginge?
Проект делаю на falsk.

Answer (score 0):

В самой MongoDB подобное обновление делается так:

```
db.collection.update({_id:id}, {$set:{Ключ: значение}})
//во втором объекте указываете поле и его новое значение.
```